# Using "apex" and "nn.Embedding" weights matrix without specify float16 reports type error

Tags: pytorch, nvidia

I have an embedding layer

> self.embedding = nn.Embedding(n,m)

I need the whole embedding weights to join computation,

> ```
>     logits = torch.einsum('bd,nd->bn', [over_states, self.embedding.weight.half()])
> ```

If I remove`.half()` in the line above, when optimizing using `apex`, I will get the data type error,

```
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mhtan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 60, in _worker
    output = module(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mhtan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mhtan/gitee/modeling_bert.py", line 551, in forward
    over_logits = self.vocab(self.over_linear(sentiment_states))
  File "/home/mhtan/gitee/modeling_bert.py", line 520, in vocab
    c_mo_logits = torch.einsum('bd,nd->bn', [over_states, self.embedding.weight])  # (b, 256, 10)
  File "/home/mhtan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/functional.py", line 201, in einsum
    return torch._C._VariableFunctions.einsum(equation, operands)
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Half but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2' in call to _th_bmm
```

I have used

```
        if args.fp16:
            try:
                from apex import amp
            except ImportError:
                raise ImportError("Please install apex from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex to use fp16 training.")
            self.model, self.optimizer = amp.initialize(self.model, self.optimizer, opt_level=args.fp16_opt_level)
```

and

```
            if self.args.fp16:
                try:
                    from apex import amp
                except ImportError:
                    raise ImportError(
                        "Please install apex from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex to use fp16 training.")
                with amp.scale_loss(loss, self.optimizer) as scaled_loss:
                    scaled_loss.backward()
```

in my training process.

It's strange to use float16 `.half()` explicitly, which package does this error may relate to, `pytorch` or `apex`?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your model with `amp.initialize` call.

Quoting [documentation](https://nvidia.github.io/apex/amp.html):

> Users **should not** manually cast their model or data to `.half()` [...]

In your case it would be something along those lines:

```
model = YourModel().cuda() # includes your embedding layer
optimizer = ... # any optimizer you want

# Usually you want O1 or O2 for mixed precision
model, optimizer = amp.initialize(model, optimizer, opt_level="O1")

with amp.scale(loss, optimizer) as scaled_loss:
    scaled_loss.backward()
```

Above should cast your model and updates appropriately for mixed precision training.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have used these lines in my code, I will update the question. Only embedding matrix is meeting this `half()` issue, other linear transformations are normal.

Comment: There are no related issues to embedding as far as I can see. You may try to temporarily remove `try`-`except` clauses and different `opt_level` values (O1, O2 or O3, first and last should be fine), though it's a long shot. If this doesn't help, you may want to file an issue on their github repo.